# How to make table updating content without refresh the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i've made a project using php ajax i use it for input data and displaying data into a table. the code work fine but when displaying data the table content didnt update the latest input in there i need to refresh page to update them.

anyone know how to make it update without refresh the whole page?
this my ajax function for input and displaying

**INPUT**

```js
$(document).on('click','#ok',function(e) {

      if ($('#netto').val() == '') {
                     alert('Kolom Netto Tolong Di Isi');
                 } else {
        var data = $("#form_input").serialize();  
        $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        url: "../php/bkk/bkk_i.php",
        success: function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data);
        }
    });
                     }
    clearInput();
});
$("#form_input").submit( function() {
  return false;
});
function clearInput() {
    $("#form_input :input").each( function() {
       $('#nopol').val('');
       $('#netto').val('');

    });


}
```

**Display**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "../php/bkk/bkk_isel.php",
            success: function(data){
  var list = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    $('#mat').val((list[i]['material']));
    $('#lok').val((list[i]['lokasi']));
    $('#kpl').val((list[i]['kapal']));
    $('#po_numb').val((list[i]['po']));
    $('#dok').val((list[i]['doc_mat']));
    var tr = "<tr>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['no']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['tanggal']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['no_pol']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>"+list[i]['netto']+"</td>";

    tr += "</tr>";

    $("#table_s tbody").append(tr);
  }
  return false;
}
});
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: when i input new data. the data in the table not updating. but when i refresh the page the data in the table will be update

Comment: i need to make it update but no need to refresh the whole page

Comment: Then it is not the problem in javascript, but php

Comment: the php code is fine. it can input data and display data nicely

Comment: No, the php code is not showing the updated data.

Comment: my problem is table refresh.. not the php input function or select funtion

Comment: Table refresh? Is your function under "display" only supposed to run while  loading the webpage? Because that is what is it doing right now. You are also overwriting the previously assigned data in the next iteration of the for loop. I mean the data being assigned to $('#mat').val(), $('#lok').val(), etc..

Comment: Yeah.. The table not refresh after new data has been input. Is it because my iteration on the function for displaying?

Comment: The iterations are not a major problem. You should give your function under "display" a name. Then call this function whenever you need this. You could use setInterval() or maybe on the .click() of a button. But if you do this you might want to add: $("#table_s tbody">tr).remove() at the start of your function. If you don't you will end up with the same data being repeated in the table.

Comment: $("#table_s tbody">tr).remove()  where i place this? 
in the code that contain of display function?

Comment: $("#table_s tbody>tr").remove(); can be placed just before the for-loop after the success: of ajax in the display function. Did you get loading the data to the table to work?

Comment: i didnt get loading data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139448/discussion-between-rmo-and-jack-henaldy).